# Why isn't my String array not working when I input it to JLabel?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I am trying to create a path choosing game similar to ones like Oregon trail. I am trying to find out why when i try to to create a JLabel to show text, the text that I am setting it to is an array in a different class, called `StoryLine`. Whenever I add the Label to my frame the text doesn't pop up on the screen. I have changed the text to `"hey"` and it worked, but for some reason it doesn't work with my array.

Consider this code:

```
public static void intro() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Lost Boy");
        JLabel textbox = Components.Textbox();
        JLabel bed = Components.Bedroom();
        JLabel text = Components.TextFormat(StoryLine.story[2]);

        frame.setSize(1000, 600);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        text.setBounds(10, -70,400,200);

        frame.add(text);
        frame.add(textbox);
        frame.add(bed);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Class for `Components.TextFormat`

```
 public static JLabel TextFormat(String stry) {
        JLabel text = new JLabel();
        text.setText(stry);
        text.setFont(MyFont());
        text.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        return text;
    }
```

Class for `StoryLine.string[]`

```
 public static void Script() {

        story[2] = "You're just putting on your shoes before you walk out the\n"
                + "door. You see your dog sitting at the door wagging his tail\n"
                + "expecting to come. Do you choose to bring him?";
```

Comment: `frame.setLayout(null);` would be your most significant issue

Comment: It looks like you initialize `story[2]` in the static method `StoryLine.Script()` however I dont see you ever calling that method, therefore `story[2]` is null as far as I can tell.

Comment: @ug_ How would i fix this?

Comment: @JoshuaSaikali well you need to call the method. You could probably put `StoryLine.Script()`  in your `intro()` method, however you might consider why that method is doing this at all. I would expect there to be a method called `StoryLine.getIntroText()` or something alike which would just return the text for you

Comment: I would also consider a non-editable `JTextArea` over a `JLabel`

Comment: Without a clear picture of what you want your UI to look like, it's impossible to make a firm recommendation. I would, however, recommend reading through [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) - remember, you can use a hierarchy of components, using different layouts, to achieve complex results

Comment: The reason for  a JTextArea instead of a JLabel is that a JLabel does not display multi-line text (unless it is formatted as HTML).

Comment: Please post [mre]